How to Resolve LINT-1 Warning During Synthesis?
I am currently working on the synthesis stage of a hardware design project and encountering a specific warning from the LINT-1. I'm seeking assistance to resolve this issue.
Tool: design compiler
Warning message:

Warning: In design 'i2s_master', cell 'C214' does not drive any nets.
(LINT-1)

RTL code:
module i2s_master(
    input clk,
    input [15:0] data_in,
    input rstn,
    input enable,
    output DATA,
    output WS
);
     
localparam IDLE=2'b00;
localparam LEFT=2'b01;
localparam RIGHT=2'b10;

reg [4:0] cnt;
reg [1:0] state;
reg [1:0] next_state;

reg [17:0] data_send;

always @(posedge clk or negedge rstn) begin
    if(!rstn) state <= IDLE;
    else if(enable) state <= next_state;
    else state <= IDLE;
end

always @(*) begin
    case(state) 
        IDLE: next_state = LEFT;
        LEFT: 
            begin
                if(cnt == 'd17) next_state = RIGHT;
                else next_state = LEFT;
            end
        RIGHT:
            begin
                if(cnt == 'd17) next_state = LEFT;
                else next_state = RIGHT;
            end
        default: next_state = IDLE;
    endcase
end

always @(posedge clk or negedge rstn) begin
    if(!rstn) cnt <= 'd0;
    else if((state != IDLE) && (cnt != 'd17)) cnt <= cnt + 1'b1;
    else cnt <= 'd0;
end

always @(posedge clk or negedge rstn) begin
    if(!rstn) data_send <= 'd0;
    else if((state == IDLE) || (cnt == 'd17)) data_send <= {data_in,2'b00};
    else data_send <= {data_send[16:0],1'b0};
end

assign WS = (state == LEFT)? 1'b1 : 1'b0;  
assign DATA = data_send[17];

endmodule

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Created by: Synopsys DC Ultra(TM) in wire load mode
// Version   : M-2016.12-SP4
// Date      : Wed Apr 24 18:40:13 2024
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

module i2s_master ( clk, data_in, rstn, enable, DATA, WS );
  input [15:0] data_in;
  input clk, rstn, enable;
  output DATA, WS;
  wire   N10, N11, N27, N28, N29, N30, N31, N35, N36, N37, N38, N39, N40, N41,
         N42, N43, N44, N45, N46, N47, N48, N49, N50, n26, n27, n28, n29, n30,
         n31, n32, n33, n34, n35, n36, n37, n38, n39, n40, n41, n42, n43, n44,
         n45, n46, n47, n48, n49, n50, n51, n52, n53, n54, n55, n56, n57;
  wire   [1:0] state;
  wire   [4:0] cnt;
  wire   [16:0] data_send;

  SDFFRHQX1 \cnt_reg[0]  ( .D(N27), .SI(1'b0), .SE(1'b0), .CK(clk), .RN(rstn), 
        .Q(cnt[0]) );
  SDFFRHQX1 \state_reg[1]  ( .D(N11), .SI(1'b0), .SE(1'b0), .CK(clk), .RN(rstn), .Q(state[1]) );
  SDFFRHQX1 \state_reg[0]  ( .D(N10), .SI(1'b0), .SE(1'b0), .CK(clk), .RN(rstn), .Q(state[0]) );
  SDFFRHQX1 \cnt_reg[1]  ( .D(N28), .SI(1'b0), .SE(1'b0), .CK(clk), .RN(rstn), 
        .Q(cnt[1]) );
  SDFFRHQX1 \cnt_reg[2]  ( .D(N29), .SI(1'b0), .SE(1'b0), .CK(clk), .RN(rstn), 
        .Q(cnt[2]) );
  SDFFRHQX1 \cnt_reg[3]  ( .D(N30), .SI(1'b0), .SE(1'b0), .CK(clk), .RN(rstn), 
        .Q(cnt[3]) );
  SDFFRHQX1 \cnt_reg[4]  ( .D(N31), .SI(1'b0), .SE(1'b0), .CK(clk), .RN(rstn), 
        .Q(cnt[4]) );
  SDFFRHQX1 \data_send_reg[2]  ( .D(N35), .SI(1'b0), .SE(1'b0), .CK(clk), .RN(
        rstn), .Q(data_send[2]) );
  SDFFRHQX1 \data_send_reg[3]  ( .D(N36), .SI(1'b0), .SE(1'b0), .CK(clk), .RN(
        rstn), .Q(data_send[3]) );
  SDFFRHQX1 \data_send_reg[4]  ( .D(N37), .SI(1'b0), .SE(1'b0), .CK(clk), .RN(
        rstn), .Q(data_send[4]) );
  SDFFRHQX1 \data_send_reg[5]  ( .D(N38), .SI(1'b0), .SE(1'b0), .CK(clk), .RN(
        rstn), .Q(data_send[5]) );
  SDFFRHQX1 \data_send_reg[6]  ( .D(N39), .SI(1'b0), .SE(1'b0), .CK(clk), .RN(
        rstn), .Q(data_send[6]) );
  SDFFRHQX1 \data_send_reg[7]  ( .D(N40), .SI(1'b0), .SE(1'b0), .CK(clk), .RN(
        rstn), .Q(data_send[7]) );
  SDFFRHQX1 \data_send_reg[8]  ( .D(N41), .SI(1'b0), .SE(1'b0), .CK(clk), .RN(
        rstn), .Q(data_send[8]) );
  SDFFRHQX1 \data_send_reg[9]  ( .D(N42), .SI(1'b0), .SE(1'b0), .CK(clk), .RN(
        rstn), .Q(data_send[9]) );
  SDFFRHQX1 \data_send_reg[10]  ( .D(N43), .SI(1'b0), .SE(1'b0), .CK(clk), 
        .RN(rstn), .Q(data_send[10]) );
  SDFFRHQX1 \data_send_reg[11]  ( .D(N44), .SI(1'b0), .SE(1'b0), .CK(clk), 
        .RN(rstn), .Q(data_send[11]) );
  SDFFRHQX1 \data_send_reg[12]  ( .D(N45), .SI(1'b0), .SE(1'b0), .CK(clk), 
        .RN(rstn), .Q(data_send[12]) );
  SDFFRHQX1 \data_send_reg[13]  ( .D(N46), .SI(1'b0), .SE(1'b0), .CK(clk), 
        .RN(rstn), .Q(data_send[13]) );
  SDFFRHQX1 \data_send_reg[14]  ( .D(N47), .SI(1'b0), .SE(1'b0), .CK(clk), 
        .RN(rstn), .Q(data_send[14]) );
  SDFFRHQX1 \data_send_reg[15]  ( .D(N48), .SI(1'b0), .SE(1'b0), .CK(clk), 
        .RN(rstn), .Q(data_send[15]) );
  SDFFRHQX1 \data_send_reg[16]  ( .D(N49), .SI(1'b0), .SE(1'b0), .CK(clk), 
        .RN(rstn), .Q(data_send[16]) );
  SDFFRHQX1 \data_send_reg[17]  ( .D(N50), .SI(1'b0), .SE(1'b0), .CK(clk), 
        .RN(rstn), .Q(DATA) );
  INVX1 U52 ( .A(state[0]), .Y(n37) );
  INVX1 U53 ( .A(state[1]), .Y(n36) );
  AOI21X1 U54 ( .A0(n37), .A1(n36), .B0(cnt[0]), .Y(N27) );
  INVX1 U55 ( .A(cnt[3]), .Y(n30) );
  NAND3X1 U56 ( .A(cnt[2]), .B(cnt[0]), .C(cnt[1]), .Y(n31) );
  NOR2X1 U57 ( .A(n30), .B(n31), .Y(n29) );
  INVX1 U58 ( .A(cnt[2]), .Y(n34) );
  NAND3X1 U59 ( .A(cnt[0]), .B(cnt[4]), .C(n34), .Y(n26) );
  NOR3XL U60 ( .A(cnt[3]), .B(cnt[1]), .C(n26), .Y(n56) );
  AOI21X1 U61 ( .A0(n37), .A1(n36), .B0(n56), .Y(n52) );
  OAI21XL U62 ( .A0(cnt[4]), .A1(n29), .B0(n52), .Y(n27) );
  AOI21X1 U63 ( .A0(cnt[4]), .A1(n29), .B0(n27), .Y(N31) );
  NAND2X1 U64 ( .A(cnt[0]), .B(cnt[1]), .Y(n33) );
  OAI211X1 U65 ( .A0(cnt[0]), .A1(cnt[1]), .B0(n33), .C0(n52), .Y(n28) );
  INVX1 U66 ( .A(n28), .Y(N28) );
  INVX1 U67 ( .A(n52), .Y(n57) );
  AOI211XL U68 ( .A0(n30), .A1(n31), .B0(n29), .C0(n57), .Y(N30) );
  INVX1 U69 ( .A(n31), .Y(n32) );
  AOI211XL U70 ( .A0(n34), .A1(n33), .B0(n32), .C0(n57), .Y(N29) );
  AOI22X1 U71 ( .A0(n52), .A1(data_send[15]), .B0(data_in[14]), .B1(n57), .Y(
        n35) );
  INVX1 U72 ( .A(n35), .Y(N49) );
  NOR2X1 U73 ( .A(state[1]), .B(n37), .Y(WS) );
  INVX1 U74 ( .A(enable), .Y(n54) );
  NOR2X1 U75 ( .A(n56), .B(n36), .Y(n55) );
  AOI22X1 U76 ( .A0(WS), .A1(n56), .B0(n55), .B1(n37), .Y(n38) );
  NOR2X1 U77 ( .A(n54), .B(n38), .Y(N11) );
  AOI22X1 U78 ( .A0(n52), .A1(data_send[2]), .B0(data_in[1]), .B1(n57), .Y(n39) );
  INVX1 U79 ( .A(n39), .Y(N36) );
  AOI22X1 U80 ( .A0(n52), .A1(data_send[3]), .B0(data_in[2]), .B1(n57), .Y(n40) );
  INVX1 U81 ( .A(n40), .Y(N37) );
  AOI22X1 U82 ( .A0(n52), .A1(data_send[4]), .B0(data_in[3]), .B1(n57), .Y(n41) );
  INVX1 U83 ( .A(n41), .Y(N38) );
  AOI22X1 U84 ( .A0(n52), .A1(data_send[16]), .B0(data_in[15]), .B1(n57), .Y(
        n42) );
  INVX1 U85 ( .A(n42), .Y(N50) );
  AOI22X1 U86 ( .A0(n52), .A1(data_send[5]), .B0(data_in[4]), .B1(n57), .Y(n43) );
  INVX1 U87 ( .A(n43), .Y(N39) );
  AOI22X1 U88 ( .A0(n52), .A1(data_send[6]), .B0(data_in[5]), .B1(n57), .Y(n44) );
  INVX1 U89 ( .A(n44), .Y(N40) );
  AOI22X1 U90 ( .A0(n52), .A1(data_send[7]), .B0(data_in[6]), .B1(n57), .Y(n45) );
  INVX1 U91 ( .A(n45), .Y(N41) );
  AOI22X1 U92 ( .A0(n52), .A1(data_send[8]), .B0(data_in[7]), .B1(n57), .Y(n46) );
  INVX1 U93 ( .A(n46), .Y(N42) );
  AOI22X1 U94 ( .A0(n52), .A1(data_send[9]), .B0(data_in[8]), .B1(n57), .Y(n47) );
  INVX1 U95 ( .A(n47), .Y(N43) );
  AOI22X1 U96 ( .A0(n52), .A1(data_send[10]), .B0(data_in[9]), .B1(n57), .Y(
        n48) );
  INVX1 U97 ( .A(n48), .Y(N44) );
  AOI22X1 U98 ( .A0(n52), .A1(data_send[11]), .B0(data_in[10]), .B1(n57), .Y(
        n49) );
  INVX1 U99 ( .A(n49), .Y(N45) );
  AOI22X1 U100 ( .A0(n52), .A1(data_send[13]), .B0(data_in[12]), .B1(n57), .Y(
        n50) );
  INVX1 U101 ( .A(n50), .Y(N47) );
  AOI22X1 U102 ( .A0(n52), .A1(data_send[12]), .B0(data_in[11]), .B1(n57), .Y(
        n51) );
  INVX1 U103 ( .A(n51), .Y(N46) );
  AOI22X1 U104 ( .A0(n52), .A1(data_send[14]), .B0(data_in[13]), .B1(n57), .Y(
        n53) );
  INVX1 U105 ( .A(n53), .Y(N48) );
  AOI211XL U106 ( .A0(n56), .A1(state[0]), .B0(n55), .C0(n54), .Y(N10) );
  AND2X2 U107 ( .A(data_in[0]), .B(n57), .Y(N35) );
endmodule

add netlist
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Created by: Synopsys Design Compiler(R)
// Version   : M-2016.12-SP4
// Date      : Thu Apr 25 17:23:16 2024
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


module i2s_master ( clk, data_in, rstn, enable, DATA, WS );
  input [15:0] data_in;
  input clk, rstn, enable;
  output DATA, WS;
  wire   N0, N1, N2, N3, N4, N5, N6, N7, N8, N9, N10, N11, N12, N13, N14, N15,
         N16, N17, N18, N19, N20, N21, N22, N23, N24, N25, N26, N27, N28, N29,
         N30, N31, N32, N33, N34, N35, N36, N37, N38, N39, N40, N41, N42, N43,
         N44, N45, N46, N47, N48, N49, N50, N51, N52, N53, N54, N55, N56, N57,
         N58, N59, N60, N61, N62, N63, N64, N65, N66, N67, N68, N69, N70, N71,
         N72, N73, N74, N75, N76, N77;
  wire   [1:0] state;
  wire   [1:0] next_state;
  wire   [4:0] cnt;
  wire   [16:0] data_send;

  \**SEQGEN**  \state_reg[1]  ( .clear(N8), .preset(1'b0), .next_state(N11), 
        .clocked_on(clk), .data_in(1'b0), .enable(1'b0), .Q(state[1]), 
        .synch_clear(1'b0), .synch_preset(1'b0), .synch_toggle(1'b0), 
        .synch_enable(1'b1) );
  \**SEQGEN**  \state_reg[0]  ( .clear(N8), .preset(1'b0), .next_state(N10), 
        .clocked_on(clk), .data_in(1'b0), .enable(1'b0), .Q(state[0]), 
        .synch_clear(1'b0), .synch_preset(1'b0), .synch_toggle(1'b0), 
        .synch_enable(1'b1) );
  GTECH_AND2 C22 ( .A(N12), .B(N51), .Z(N13) );
  GTECH_OR2 C24 ( .A(state[1]), .B(N51), .Z(N14) );
  GTECH_OR2 C27 ( .A(N12), .B(state[0]), .Z(N16) );
  GTECH_AND2 C29 ( .A(state[1]), .B(state[0]), .Z(N18) );
  \**SEQGEN**  \cnt_reg[4]  ( .clear(N8), .preset(1'b0), .next_state(N31), 
        .clocked_on(clk), .data_in(1'b0), .enable(1'b0), .Q(cnt[4]), 
        .synch_clear(1'b0), .synch_preset(1'b0), .synch_toggle(1'b0), 
        .synch_enable(1'b1) );
  \**SEQGEN**  \cnt_reg[3]  ( .clear(N8), .preset(1'b0), .next_state(N30), 
        .clocked_on(clk), .data_in(1'b0), .enable(1'b0), .Q(cnt[3]), 
        .synch_clear(1'b0), .synch_preset(1'b0), .synch_toggle(1'b0), 
        .synch_enable(1'b1) );
  \**SEQGEN**  \cnt_reg[2]  ( .clear(N8), .preset(1'b0), .next_state(N29), 
        .clocked_on(clk), .data_in(1'b0), .enable(1'b0), .Q(cnt[2]), 
        .synch_clear(1'b0), .synch_preset(1'b0), .synch_toggle(1'b0), 
        .synch_enable(1'b1) );
  \**SEQGEN**  \cnt_reg[1]  ( .clear(N8), .preset(1'b0), .next_state(N28), 
        .clocked_on(clk), .data_in(1'b0), .enable(1'b0), .Q(cnt[1]), 
        .synch_clear(1'b0), .synch_preset(1'b0), .synch_toggle(1'b0), 
        .synch_enable(1'b1) );
  \**SEQGEN**  \cnt_reg[0]  ( .clear(N8), .preset(1'b0), .next_state(N27), 
        .clocked_on(clk), .data_in(1'b0), .enable(1'b0), .Q(cnt[0]), 
        .synch_clear(1'b0), .synch_preset(1'b0), .synch_toggle(1'b0), 
        .synch_enable(1'b1) );
  \**SEQGEN**  \data_send_reg[17]  ( .clear(N8), .preset(1'b0), .next_state(
        N50), .clocked_on(clk), .data_in(1'b0), .enable(1'b0), .Q(DATA), 
        .synch_clear(1'b0), .synch_preset(1'b0), .synch_toggle(1'b0), 
        .synch_enable(1'b1) );
  \**SEQGEN**  \data_send_reg[16]  ( .clear(N8), .preset(1'b0), .next_state(
        N49), .clocked_on(clk), .data_in(1'b0), .enable(1'b0), .Q(
        data_send[16]), .synch_clear(1'b0), .synch_preset(1'b0), 
        .synch_toggle(1'b0), .synch_enable(1'b1) );
  \**SEQGEN**  \data_send_reg[15]  ( .clear(N8), .preset(1'b0), .next_state(
        N48), .clocked_on(clk), .data_in(1'b0), .enable(1'b0), .Q(
        data_send[15]), .synch_clear(1'b0), .synch_preset(1'b0), 
        .synch_toggle(1'b0), .synch_enable(1'b1) );
  \**SEQGEN**  \data_send_reg[14]  ( .clear(N8), .preset(1'b0), .next_state(
        N47), .clocked_on(clk), .data_in(1'b0), .enable(1'b0), .Q(
        data_send[14]), .synch_clear(1'b0), .synch_preset(1'b0), 
        .synch_toggle(1'b0), .synch_enable(1'b1) );
  \**SEQGEN**  \data_send_reg[13]  ( .clear(N8), .preset(1'b0), .next_state(
        N46), .clocked_on(clk), .data_in(1'b0), .enable(1'b0), .Q(
        data_send[13]), .synch_clear(1'b0), .synch_preset(1'b0), 
        .synch_toggle(1'b0), .synch_enable(1'b1) );
  \**SEQGEN**  \data_send_reg[12]  ( .clear(N8), .preset(1'b0), .next_state(
        N45), .clocked_on(clk), .data_in(1'b0), .enable(1'b0), .Q(
        data_send[12]), .synch_clear(1'b0), .synch_preset(1'b0), 
        .synch_toggle(1'b0), .synch_enable(1'b1) );
  \**SEQGEN**  \data_send_reg[11]  ( .clear(N8), .preset(1'b0), .next_state(
        N44), .clocked_on(clk), .data_in(1'b0), .enable(1'b0), .Q(
        data_send[11]), .synch_clear(1'b0), .synch_preset(1'b0), 
        .synch_toggle(1'b0), .synch_enable(1'b1) );
  \**SEQGEN**  \data_send_reg[10]  ( .clear(N8), .preset(1'b0), .next_state(
        N43), .clocked_on(clk), .data_in(1'b0), .enable(1'b0), .Q(
        data_send[10]), .synch_clear(1'b0), .synch_preset(1'b0), 
        .synch_toggle(1'b0), .synch_enable(1'b1) );
  \**SEQGEN**  \data_send_reg[9]  ( .clear(N8), .preset(1'b0), .next_state(N42), .clocked_on(clk), .data_in(1'b0), .enable(1'b0), .Q(data_send[9]), 
        .synch_clear(1'b0), .synch_preset(1'b0), .synch_toggle(1'b0), 
        .synch_enable(1'b1) );
  \**SEQGEN**  \data_send_reg[8]  ( .clear(N8), .preset(1'b0), .next_state(N41), .clocked_on(clk), .data_in(1'b0), .enable(1'b0), .Q(data_send[8]), 
        .synch_clear(1'b0), .synch_preset(1'b0), .synch_toggle(1'b0), 
        .synch_enable(1'b1) );
  \**SEQGEN**  \data_send_reg[7]  ( .clear(N8), .preset(1'b0), .next_state(N40), .clocked_on(clk), .data_in(1'b0), .enable(1'b0), .Q(data_send[7]), 
        .synch_clear(1'b0), .synch_preset(1'b0), .synch_toggle(1'b0), 
        .synch_enable(1'b1) );
  \**SEQGEN**  \data_send_reg[6]  ( .clear(N8), .preset(1'b0), .next_state(N39), .clocked_on(clk), .data_in(1'b0), .enable(1'b0), .Q(data_send[6]), 
        .synch_clear(1'b0), .synch_preset(1'b0), .synch_toggle(1'b0), 
        .synch_enable(1'b1) );
  \**SEQGEN**  \data_send_reg[5]  ( .clear(N8), .preset(1'b0), .next_state(N38), .clocked_on(clk), .data_in(1'b0), .enable(1'b0), .Q(data_send[5]), 
        .synch_clear(1'b0), .synch_preset(1'b0), .synch_toggle(1'b0), 
        .synch_enable(1'b1) );
  \**SEQGEN**  \data_send_reg[4]  ( .clear(N8), .preset(1'b0), .next_state(N37), .clocked_on(clk), .data_in(1'b0), .enable(1'b0), .Q(data_send[4]), 
        .synch_clear(1'b0), .synch_preset(1'b0), .synch_toggle(1'b0), 
        .synch_enable(1'b1) );
  \**SEQGEN**  \data_send_reg[3]  ( .clear(N8), .preset(1'b0), .next_state(N36), .clocked_on(clk), .data_in(1'b0), .enable(1'b0), .Q(data_send[3]), 
        .synch_clear(1'b0), .synch_preset(1'b0), .synch_toggle(1'b0), 
        .synch_enable(1'b1) );
  \**SEQGEN**  \data_send_reg[2]  ( .clear(N8), .preset(1'b0), .next_state(N35), .clocked_on(clk), .data_in(1'b0), .enable(1'b0), .Q(data_send[2]), 
        .synch_clear(1'b0), .synch_preset(1'b0), .synch_toggle(1'b0), 
        .synch_enable(1'b1) );
  \**SEQGEN**  \data_send_reg[1]  ( .clear(N8), .preset(1'b0), .next_state(N34), .clocked_on(clk), .data_in(1'b0), .enable(1'b0), .Q(data_send[1]), 
        .synch_clear(1'b0), .synch_preset(1'b0), .synch_toggle(1'b0), 
        .synch_enable(1'b1) );
  \**SEQGEN**  \data_send_reg[0]  ( .clear(N8), .preset(1'b0), .next_state(
        1'b0), .clocked_on(clk), .data_in(1'b0), .enable(1'b0), .Q(
        data_send[0]), .synch_clear(1'b0), .synch_preset(1'b0), .synch_toggle(
        1'b0), .synch_enable(1'b1) );
  GTECH_NOT I_0 ( .A(state[0]), .Z(N51) );
  GTECH_OR2 C149 ( .A(N51), .B(state[1]), .Z(N52) );
  GTECH_NOT I_1 ( .A(N52), .Z(N53) );
  GTECH_OR2 C151 ( .A(state[0]), .B(state[1]), .Z(N54) );
  GTECH_NOT I_2 ( .A(N54), .Z(N55) );
  GTECH_NOT I_3 ( .A(cnt[4]), .Z(N56) );
  GTECH_NOT I_4 ( .A(cnt[0]), .Z(N57) );
  GTECH_OR2 C155 ( .A(cnt[3]), .B(N56), .Z(N58) );
  GTECH_OR2 C156 ( .A(cnt[2]), .B(N58), .Z(N59) );
  GTECH_OR2 C157 ( .A(cnt[1]), .B(N59), .Z(N60) );
  GTECH_OR2 C158 ( .A(N57), .B(N60), .Z(N61) );
  GTECH_NOT I_5 ( .A(N61), .Z(N62) );
  GTECH_OR2 C162 ( .A(cnt[3]), .B(N56), .Z(N63) );
  GTECH_OR2 C163 ( .A(cnt[2]), .B(N63), .Z(N64) );
  GTECH_OR2 C164 ( .A(cnt[1]), .B(N64), .Z(N65) );
  GTECH_OR2 C165 ( .A(N57), .B(N65), .Z(N66) );
  GTECH_NOT I_6 ( .A(N66), .Z(N67) );
  GTECH_OR2 C169 ( .A(cnt[3]), .B(N56), .Z(N68) );
  GTECH_OR2 C170 ( .A(cnt[2]), .B(N68), .Z(N69) );
  GTECH_OR2 C171 ( .A(cnt[1]), .B(N69), .Z(N70) );
  GTECH_OR2 C172 ( .A(N57), .B(N70), .Z(N71) );
  GTECH_NOT I_7 ( .A(N71), .Z(N72) );
  GTECH_OR2 C174 ( .A(state[0]), .B(state[1]), .Z(N73) );
  GTECH_OR2 C179 ( .A(cnt[3]), .B(N56), .Z(N74) );
  GTECH_OR2 C180 ( .A(cnt[2]), .B(N74), .Z(N75) );
  GTECH_OR2 C181 ( .A(cnt[1]), .B(N75), .Z(N76) );
  GTECH_OR2 C182 ( .A(N57), .B(N76), .Z(N77) );
  ADD_UNS_OP add_45_S2 ( .A(cnt), .B(1'b1), .Z({N26, N25, N24, N23, N22}) );
  SELECT_OP C185 ( .DATA1(next_state), .DATA2({1'b0, 1'b0}), .CONTROL1(N0), 
        .CONTROL2(N1), .Z({N11, N10}) );
  GTECH_BUF B_0 ( .A(enable), .Z(N0) );
  GTECH_BUF B_1 ( .A(N9), .Z(N1) );
  SELECT_OP C188 ( .DATA1({1'b0, 1'b1}), .DATA2({N67, N66}), .DATA3({N71, N72}), .DATA4({1'b0, 1'b0}), .CONTROL1(N2), .CONTROL2(N3), .CONTROL3(N4), 
        .CONTROL4(N5), .Z(next_state) );
  GTECH_BUF B_2 ( .A(N13), .Z(N2) );
  GTECH_BUF B_3 ( .A(N15), .Z(N3) );
  GTECH_BUF B_4 ( .A(N17), .Z(N4) );
  GTECH_BUF B_5 ( .A(N18), .Z(N5) );
  SELECT_OP C189 ( .DATA1({N26, N25, N24, N23, N22}), .DATA2({1'b0, 1'b0, 1'b0, 
        1'b0, 1'b0}), .CONTROL1(N6), .CONTROL2(N21), .Z({N31, N30, N29, N28, 
        N27}) );
  GTECH_BUF B_6 ( .A(N20), .Z(N6) );
  SELECT_OP C190 ( .DATA1({data_in, 1'b0}), .DATA2(data_send), .CONTROL1(N7), 
        .CONTROL2(N33), .Z({N50, N49, N48, N47, N46, N45, N44, N43, N42, N41, 
        N40, N39, N38, N37, N36, N35, N34}) );
  GTECH_BUF B_7 ( .A(N32), .Z(N7) );
  GTECH_NOT I_8 ( .A(rstn), .Z(N8) );
  GTECH_NOT I_9 ( .A(enable), .Z(N9) );
  GTECH_NOT I_10 ( .A(state[1]), .Z(N12) );
  GTECH_NOT I_11 ( .A(N14), .Z(N15) );
  GTECH_NOT I_12 ( .A(N16), .Z(N17) );
  GTECH_BUF B_8 ( .A(rstn), .Z(N19) );
  GTECH_AND2 C211 ( .A(N73), .B(N77), .Z(N20) );
  GTECH_NOT I_13 ( .A(N20), .Z(N21) );
  GTECH_AND2 C214 ( .A(N19), .B(N20) );
  GTECH_OR2 C215 ( .A(N55), .B(N62), .Z(N32) );
  GTECH_NOT I_14 ( .A(N32), .Z(N33) );
  GTECH_BUF B_9 ( .A(N53), .Z(WS) );
endmodule


What approaches can be taken to address this type of warning in LINT-1?
What changes or checks should be made in the code?

You should review the full synthesis report, not just the one line that you posted.  Also, refer to the Design Compiler documentation which has a detailed "Description" of the LINT-1 warning message as well as a "What Next" recommendation for how to address the warning.
I suspect cell C214 is related to the data_send signal.
In the RTL code, you declared the signal as 18 bits.  However, the 2 LSB's ([1:0]) are always 0.
Also, in the synthesis output Verilog module, data_send is only 17 bits, not 18.  Bits [1:0] are not connected.
Keep in mind that some warnings can be ignored, while you should address others.  You need to make this decision based on the work you have done to assure that the design behaves as desired:

RTL simulations pass with high code coverage
Gate netlist with back-annotated delays (SDF) simulations also pass
The design meets the timing constraints
Etc.


I found out where the C214 cell is located. Therefore, I will add the netlist containing C214 in the main text.
How should I modify the RTL code to resolve the LINT-1 Warning?

@강영완: Like I said, you may not need to resolve the warning if your design works as you expect.

Is there no solution for the LINT-1 Warning?
Does the LINT-1 Warning frequently occur in actual practice, and is it often ignored without resolution?

@강영완: The only thing that matters to you is whether the warning indicates a problem for your code or not.  In the 4 days since you posted this question, you should have been able to prove if your code works as desired (or not).
